# The best way to copy the the input values between two view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two different views which have the same number of fields (checkbox type) to be filled out.

I need to copy the values from one view to the other when clicking on the copy button..

Here is my code which works:

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var firstInputSet = $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity').find('input'),
        secondInputSet = $('#contest_data_reminderPeriodicity').find('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < firstInputSet.length; i ++) {
        //console.log($(firstInputSet[i]).prop('checked'));
        $(secondInputSet[i]).prop('checked', $(firstInputSet[i]).prop('checked'))
    }
});​
```

I would like to know if there is a best way to do this job.

Here is the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2639/

Comment: For the way you have your variables set up, this method is acceptable. I would have set up the names/IDs on the page differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the first part.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/2641/

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $("#second-set").empty();
    $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity').clone().appendTo("#second-set").attr("id", "contest_data_second")
});​
```

Pros: If you decide to add something, you don't have to add it twice.

Cons: Will probably have to rethink your "get" function, since the original and duplicate inputs share the same name attribute. Easy to remedy though.

Answer (score 0):

Just filter your search for only checkbox type and use the each method.

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var firstInputSet = $('#contest_data_updatePeriodicity').find('input:checkbox');
    var secondInputSet = $('#contest_data_reminderPeriodicity').find('input:checkbox');
    secondInputSet.each(function(i) { $(this).prop('checked', $(firstInputSet[i]).prop('checked')) });
});​
```